# PHP validation check

Tags: php, forms, validation

Im trying to create a validation form for the site im working on, and whislt if the post requests work without the validation, as soon as I begin to introduce a simple count to prevent the query being sent, it stops working

```
<?php
$ErrorCount = 0;
$StudentNO = $_POST['updateid'];
$editfirst = $_POST['updatefirst'];
$editSurname = $_POST['updatesurn'];


$editfirst = test_input($editfirst);
$editSurname = test_input($editSurname);
$StudentNO = test_input2($StudentNO);

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $data);
    if(preg_match('/drop table/i', $data)) {
        $data == null;
    }
    if($data == null) {
        $ErrorCount++;
    }
}

function test_input2($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "", $data);
    if(preg_match('/drop table/i', $data)) {
        $data == null;
    }
    if(strlen($StudentNO) != 6) {
        $ErrorCount++;
    }
    if($data == null) {
        $ErrorCount++;
    }
}


if($ErrorCount == 0) {
    $server = 'sql.rde.hull.ac.uk';
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_556278");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $connectionInfo);

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE Users SET Firstname = '$editfirst', Surname = '$editSurname' WHERE StudentID = '$StudentNO';";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $updateQuery);

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $updateQuery);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
}
?>
```

The issue is that the errorcount isn't being increased or passed to anything, any help as I just can't see my error. I am very new to php

```
<?php
updateQuery = "INSERT INTO Locations (StudentID, ,[Location], [DateTime]) VALUES (?, ?, GETDATE());";
$params = array($UpdateStudent, $UpdateLocation);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $updateQuery, $params);
?>
```

Comment: Variable Scope! [Check it out](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) You are setting a new `$ErrorCount` created inside the funtion. That is not that same `$ErrorCount` as the one in the main scope

Comment: ah so how would I go about incrementing the counter? it works as is except for variable names on a separate page?

Comment: The whole premise of this code is based on bad research. If you want to avoid SQL Injection use parameterised and bound queries. Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: And this kinda explains you new error with the insert `StudentID, ,[Location],` you have 2 commas one after the other

Comment: its mssql sorry should have specified, and I whilst that was the goal, I currently don't have time to implement the changes

Comment: And `$updateQuery` !== `updateQuery` variables must start with a `$`

Comment: Why not, you put them into the INSERT query

Comment: oh sorry I missed off the $ that is already there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the function definition to something like:

```
function test_input($data,$ErrorCount) { /*code....*/ }

function test_input2($data,$ErrorCount) { /*code....*/ }
```

Comment: Changed it to actually return a result, that was part of the issue however its coming across another issue, and I can't tell where its coming from, online checkers say its this

    $updateQuery = "INSERT INTO Locations (StudentID, ,[Location], [DateTime]) VALUES (?, ?, GETDATE());";   
     
    but its been fine before

Comment: Sam you dont show us any code that contains an INSERT query !?!?!?!